QuestDB how to configure dense insert
I'm new in TSDB and I configured a GuestDB and Telegraf as gateway from an Opcua input. All the components are working as expected and i note that each single row (for all input tags) has the correspondant value and timestamp,  an the colum name are null.
I'm asking how is it possible to have a more dense form where timestamp in common for all the values in the differents columns ?
From:
OpcItemID.X, timestamp, valueX, null, null
OpcItemID.Y, timestamp, null, Valley, null
OpcItemID.Z, timestamp, null, null, Valdez

to
Empty, timestamp, valueX, Valley, valueZ
Where i can find some i input? fir that, seems that aggregators.merge is not working ...
Alberto
Tried the aggregator.merge but is not working
